# Understanding quadratic root

Tags: roots

Quadratic root is defined as $\sqrt{ x^2} = |x|$. Easy to remember, but seems to lack logic. And this topic is about you proving me wrong.

1) This definition of a square root is not universal and is restricted to one special case when $x \in R$.

2) And how do we define roots of higher orders then? $\sqrt[4]16 = 2,2i$ (I do not add two more negative answers because of that "absolute value" trick). That means $\sqrt[4]{x^4} = |x|$ is not a function as it returns two values.

3) "Square root has to return only one value, otherwise it is not function. And we want really badly square root to be a function, thus we force it to return an absolute value". Sounds pretty much like the most convincing explanation to me for such a definition. As of my understanding square root (just like roots of other orders) returns more than one value thus is not a function and should not be forced to resemble one

Comment: Complex numbers have no "sign" (positive/negative) as real numbers do, so the above doesn't apply for them, and for negative numbers it works just fine: $\;\sqrt{(-2)^2}=2=|-2|\;$ , for example

Comment: By definition, "negative number" is one that is *less than zero*. Since the complex cannot be ordered, there is no "less than" or "more than" in the complex numbers. What you mean is that we have the **notation** $\;-z\;$ for the additive inverse of a complex number.

Comment: And how do I thumb your remark up now. You are very right

Comment: Thank you, don't worry about that. Most probably you'll have to wait for more reputation points (?) in order to be able to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

There are several functions here. As far as I remember:

1)
$\sqrt[2n]x$ for x real is defined for $x \geq 0$ only ($n\geq1$ is an integer).
It's a function returning a single real value which is non-negative.

2)
$\sqrt[2n+1]x$ for x real is defined for all real x ($n \geq 1$ integer).
It's a function returning a single real value (it can be negative).

3) 
$\sqrt[n]z$ for z complex is defined for all complex z.
It's a multi-valued function which returns $n$ complex numbers.
Note that if you take a real number and use that third definition,
it works OK. One of the roots returned here coincides with the root
/returned by 1) or 2)/, if such a root exists / as per 1) or 2) /.
So this third definition is more general than 1) and 2), it builds upon them.

Of course this idea of root can be further extended and refined,
but at a certain level of knowledge I think this idea of roots is OK
and makes total sense.

Comment: 4 is a complex number (it's imaginary part equals to zero). And when we write $\sqrt4$, what do we refer to? The first definition you have mentioned of a square root or the third one? They return different answers

Comment: When we write $\sqrt4$ we usually mean definition 1) unless we explicitly say otherwise.

Comment: 1) returns 2 while 3) returns {2,-2}. So ... right, the return different things, but one of the answers returned by 3) is the complex number 2 i.e. the same root returned by 1). The other one returned by 3) is the complex number −2 + 0i (which also happens to be purely real). So 3) is an extension of 1) and 2), something more general. That's what mathematicians want when they extend from reals to complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In the complex numbers, there are essentially two choices for defining $\sqrt[n]{z}$:

1. Make this a "multivalued function" with $n$ different values (for $z \ne 0$)
2. Choose a particular branch, i.e. for each $z$ one of the $n$ roots is singled out as the one you want.  This can't be done in a way that is continuous on the whole complex plane: you will always have a "branch cut", a curve extending from $0$ to complex $\infty$ along which the function is discontinuous.

For example, the **principal branch** can be defined as follows: if $z = r e^{i\theta}$ with $r \ge 0$ and $-\pi < \theta \le \pi$, then
the principal branch of $\sqrt[n]{z}$ is $ r^{1/n} e^{i\theta/n}$.